# font-face: Inline font only rendering nice in IE

Tags: css, font-face

I got the [Homestead](http://www.losttype.com/font/?name=homestead) font from the Lost Type Co-op, which has font-face support. Using Font Squirrel, I got an @font-face package. I included everything and wanted to use the Inline variant as demonstrated [here](http://www.bramvandersype.be). This is my CSS:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'HomesteadInline';
    src: url('homestead/homestead-inline-webfont.eot');
    src: url('homestead/homestead-inline-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('homestead/homestead-inline-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('homestead/homestead-inline-webfont.svg#HomesteadInline') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
h1 { font-family: 'HomesteadInline'; font-size: 10em}
```

The font works, but renders horribly in Chrome and Firefox, the only browser that I tested that does it right is IE9.

Below is a comparison screenshot:
[image]

Is there any way of fixing this?

Comment: Define *renders horribly*. Got some screenshots for comparison?

Comment: Added screenshot as a comparison, you can also see it live at bramvandersype.be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had issues with the font-weight of homestead across different browsers.
Try adding `font-weight:200;` when you use homestead

Comment: That actually did the trick, it was because Bootstrap was setting the titles as bold.